# Combine two separate joins in one query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two separate inner join queries I need to combine into one query as I am looking for records that meet a Yes/No (0/1) flag in either of two fields. They are both joining the same tables but with two different 'On' conditions.

To simplify it would be:

`Select J.ID,C.Flag1 from Table1 J
Inner Join Table2 C
On J.FlagID=C.ID`

and

`Select J.ID,C.Flag2 from Table1 J
Inner Join Table2 C
On J.CustomName=C.Name`

Comment: HINT:  `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union tag is your friend here

```
(Select J.ID,C.Flag1 from Table1 J
Inner Join Table2 C
On J.FlagID=C.ID) UNION (Select J.ID,C.Flag2 from Table1 J
Inner Join Table2 C
On J.CustomName=C.Name)
```

it should be noted that union deletes duplicates and also requires equivalent fields between the two queries. so you can't simply do (select name from a) union (select name, country from b);